# Research in the workplace reveals that people work for many reasons _______

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositions, sentence-meaning

Research in the workplace reveals that people work for many reasons _______.

(1)  beside money,

(2)  besides money

---

Answer is given :  besides money.

But, google says "besides" means "in addition to"; and also "apart from". I am confused that here meaning is opposite each other?

Google says "beside" means "in addition to; apart from". Ok, then what is difference, between "beside" and "besides"?

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Read [this](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/difference-between-beside-and-besides-preposition-adverb)

Comment: @user178049, good post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides and beside are two words that are often confused. Grammatically, besides is an adverb or a preposition, and beside a preposition.

Beside

Beside means next to:

> > A house beside the sea
> >     She sat beside her friend.

Besides

As a preposition, besides means in addition to or apart from

> > What are you studying besides English? (in addition to)
> >     Who was there besides Jon? (apart from)

As an adverb, besides means as well or furthermore.

> > He was scruffy and badly prepared. Besides, he turned up late for the interview.

(Lifted entirely from) https://www.usingenglish.com/articles/beside-besides.html